# How to convert weeks into months and sum values

Tags: python, pandas

I've a dataset such as follows

Index Sku  Week Sales

0
SKU1442 201420 1904.0

1
SKU1442 201421 692.0

2
SKU1442 201422 842.0

3
SKU1442 201423 1013.0

4
SKU1442 201424 362.0

5
SKU1442 201425 279.0

6
SKU1442 201426 430.0

7
SKU1442 201427 861.0

8
SKU1442 201428 1069.0

9
SKU1442 201429 721.0

I'm trying to sum sales across the months based on the year and week numbers. for eg 201406 ->9999,  201407 -> 100

So far I've been able to convert the week into date using function as;

```
dt = datetime.strptime('201420'+ '1', '%Y%W%w')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) first and then [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
df['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Week'].astype(str) + '1', format='%Y%W%w')

df = df.resample('M', on='Week').sum()
print (df)
             Sales
Week              
2014-05-31  2596.0
2014-06-30  2926.0
2014-07-31  2651.0
```

Alternative solution is convert to `month` period by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df['Week'].dt.to_period('m')).sum()
print (df)
          Sales
Week           
2014-05  2596.0
2014-06  2926.0
2014-07  2651.0
```

EDIT: For better sample was changed input data in `ISku` column:

```
print (df)
      ISku    Week   Sales
0  SKU1442  201420  1904.0
1  SKU1442  201421   692.0
2  SKU1442  201422   842.0
3  SKU1442  201423  1013.0
4  SKU1444  201424   362.0
5  SKU1444  201425   279.0
6  SKU1444  201426   430.0
7  SKU1444  201427   861.0
8  SKU1444  201428  1069.0
9  SKU1442  201429   721.0

df['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Week'].astype(str) + '1', format='%Y%W%w')

df = df.groupby(['ISku',df['Week'].dt.to_period('m')]).sum().reset_index()
print (df)
      ISku    Week   Sales
0  SKU1442 2014-05  2596.0
1  SKU1442 2014-06  1855.0
2  SKU1442 2014-07   721.0
3  SKU1444 2014-06  1071.0
4  SKU1444 2014-07  1930.0
```

Comment: is their a way I can keep the SKU column in this df because I have multiple values in SKU

Comment: @user6083088 - Do you think get `sum` per `ISku` and `month+year`s ? If yes, please check edited answer.

Comment: if only I could write code like you @jezrael - thank you